# Is it possible to identify the FacesMessage.Severity in view?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I set the message like the following:

**Info**

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Done",  null);
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", message);
```

**Error**

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, " not found.",  null);
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("messages", message);
```

***in the UI i show like the following***

```
<p:messages id="messages" for="messages" globalOnly="true" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" autoUpdate="true" closable="false" style="font-size: 12px;" />
```

Is it possible to identify the `javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.Severity` and do some action accordingly?

Like my case is I have to close the current window if the `javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.Severity` is INFO else don't close the window.

How do I handle this in JSF?

Comment: `#{facesContext.maximumSeverity}`

Comment: @JasperdeVries thanks and how to close the current window if the javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.Severity is FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO ?

Comment: Use EL in the `closable` attribute in `<p:messages ...>`.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Not the message window but the current window itself

Comment: Simply add some Javascript based on the maximum severity.